# Pangya: Fantasy Golf - Papel Shop Special Items

Tags: pangya-fantasy-golf

I've recently become hopelessly addicted to **Pangya: Fantasy Golf** for the **PSP**. However, there seems to be hopelessly little information on it from my usual sources.

What I am looking for is information on how the Papel Shop chooses when to change the special items available. I'm theorizing that it changes after so much time not playing the game, as it changed overnight, but not once during my playtime this morning. Including across loading the save and turning off the PSP.

Anyone able to confirm / correct this theory?

Update: I've changed my theory on this situation to it changing every 24 hours, at midnight, according to the PSP internal clock. It didn't change at all yesterday... but it had changed when I got up this morning. Still looking for confirmation or correction, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/955277-pangya-fantasy-golf/50188269) seems to agree that the items reset at the start of each day (according to the PSP internal clock).

Additionally, "if you enter the store, see stuff you don't like, then exit the game without exiting the shop (power off/home screen), it'll have different items the next time you go to the store."

Comment: Thanks! Wish I'd have known about the reset trick before spending all my pang essentially gambling. lol